# Modal backup for browsers with Javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

We're redesigning some of the user interface on our site, and one step that we would like to take to make it cleaner is to use a modal window for login/sign-up actions.

I am concerned though about the impact this might have on the few users who have javascript disabled, and am curious how that is normally handled.  What's the best practice for that scenario?

Comment: I always use a regular link that points to `/register/` and cancel the click event using JavaScript in order to display a modal dialog.

Comment: I never worry about people who disable javascript in 2013. If someone turns it off then he should be ready to get bad UI and worst experience. Show noscript warning is enough. If however business requires to support paranoiacs then what Blender said is proper solution.

Comment: @dfsq - I'd normally agree with you, but since customers need to use our application to manage recurring bills, there is a worry that anything which would prevent a user from being able to log on could be seen as an undue burden on their ability to stop payments/cancel their account (from a legal perspective).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the modal link href to /whatever?modal=true. If JS is available, hijack the click and show the modal. If not, reload the page and display the modal using a conditional class in your template.

Yes, ~99% of users will have JS enabled, but graceful degradation/progressive enhancement techniques will help ensure that your site will continue to be usable if *your* JS isn't available for whatever reason (error, downed CDN, etc.).